# wkhtmltopdf is not working on live shared hosting

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

I have deployed my Laravel project on a shared host. In my project I'm using wkhhtmltopdf which is working fine on localhost, but is not working on live server and giving this error:

> RuntimeException in AbstractGenerator.php line 336: The exit status code '127' says something went wrong: stderr: "sh: 1: /hermes/bosweb26a/b2003/ywh.xorlogics1/client/shisha/invoices/vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd‌​64: not found " stdout: "" command: /hermes/bosweb26a/b2003/ywh.xorlogics1/client/shisha/invoices/vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd‌​64 --lowquality '/tmp/knp_snappy57cecf069e11a3.25644949.html' '/tmp/knp_snappy57cecf069e1ff3.62352750.pdf'. "

Comment: Are you sure the shared host supports wkhtmltopdf, and has all the dependencies (e.g. libXrender) installed?

Comment: As we have only access to shared hosting through control panel so we cant not install this package from ssh. Also we have discussed this issue with them , but they are not allowed to install this as this is a shared hosting.

Comment: Get a VPS instead of shared hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Wkhtmltopdf is a module that needs to be installed on the operating system. I think that the module is not installed on the shared host. If ever you have access to the shared host (ssh for example for a linux server) try to install wkhtmltopdf, or else try to get it installed by the hosting provider if possible.

**Edit**

In case that's impossible to get wkhtmlmodule installed on the shared hosting, the only solution is to switch to virtual or dedicated server plan. VPS (virtual private server) is a good alternative with prices sometimes almost the same as shared hosting.

Comment: We don't have access to shared server through ssh as we have only control panel access. I have discussed this issue with the support team and they are saying that they can not install any kind of packages on shared hosting and that i need to buy a dedicated server.
Is there any alternate solution to fix this, Please let me know.

In windows we can access this package from vendor folder but why not on Linux shared hosting as it present in vendor folder.

Comment: With shared hosting there are always such limitations (because many users are on the same server et we don't own the server to control it). What I would do in your case is to switch to a virtual private server (vps), the prices  are very interesting and you have total control on the virtual server.